# Wyomind Running schema recurring

Tags: magento2

Ran into an issue an unable to diagnose any ideas would be helpful.

Upgraded to 2.3.7-p1 and everything works fine with the exception of a few Wyomind Modules. Running setup:upgrade I continually see the following:

```
Module 'Wyomind_Framework':
Running schema recurring...
Copying files for Magento 2.3.7

Module 'Wyomind_DataFeedManager':
Module 'Wyomind_CronScheduler':
Running schema recurring...
Copying files for Magento 2.3.7
```

I can run setup:di:compile and there is no errors generated. I also reviewed the system and exception logs and see no errors. Any suggestions as to how to go about diagnosing the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So we don't have logs and errors.

Maybe we should go inside Wyomid_* module and check what happens with the code:

```
Wyomid_*/Setup/RecurringData.class
```

My pleasure!